# Cordova WebRTC - Lollipop only

Tags: cordova, webrtc, android-5.0-lollipop

I am trying to get WebRTC running from within a Cordova app.
This is only meant to run with Android Lollipop, which supports WebRTC.

So far it starts initializing the camera, but gets to the errorCallback.

Here is my ADB log:

```
17929-17950/app D/ChromiumCameraInfo﹕ Camera enumerated: front
17929-17950/app D/ChromiumCameraInfo﹕ Camera enumerated: back
223-2895/? W/AudioFlinger﹕ acquireAudioSessionId() unknown client 17929 for session 481
223-2895/? W/AudioFlinger﹕ acquireAudioSessionId() unknown client 17929 for session 482
223-2895/? I/Camera2ClientBase﹕ Camera 1: Opened. Client: app (PID 17929, UID 10088)
223-2895/? I/NvCameraHalLogging﹕ NvCameraHalLogging:Preview profile reset
510-1032/? I/CwMcuSensor﹕ CwMcuSensor::flush: fd = 199, sensors_id = 0, path = /sys/class/htc_sensorhub/sensor_hub/flush, err = 0
223-2895/? D/NvOsDebugPrintf﹕ NvPclHwCreateModuleListOne: WARNING: Could not map module to ISP config string
223-2895/? D/NvOsDebugPrintf﹕ NvPclHwCreateModuleListOne: WARNING: Could not map module to ISP config string
223-2895/? D/NvOsDebugPrintf﹕ SensorBayer_SetPowerLevel 3
223-2895/? D/NvOsDebugPrintf﹕ OV9760 Camera fd open as: 55
223-2895/? D/NvOsDebugPrintf﹕ NvCameraIspInitialize: disable3A=0x0
223-2895/? D/NvOsDebugPrintf﹕ AFConfigParamsSanityCheck: Warning: settle_time too large: 100, capped to 30
223-2895/? D/NvOsDebugPrintf﹕ -- NvIspAFinit -- min 0, max 0
223-2895/? D/NvOsDebugPrintf﹕ NvIspSetStats: WARNING: FM can't be enabled because AP is not enabled!!
223-2895/? D/NvOsDebugPrintf﹕ SensorBayer_SetPowerLevel 3
223-2895/? E/Camera2-Parameters﹕ buildFastInfo: Unknown override AE mode: 0
223-17992/? D/NvOsDebugPrintf﹕ NvCamScaler_OutputThread-- (error 0x0)
223-652/? D/NvOsDebugPrintf﹕ SensorBayer_SetPowerLevel 1
223-15351/? I/Camera2ClientBase﹕ Camera 0: Opened. Client: app (PID 17929, UID 10088)
223-15351/? I/NvCameraHalLogging﹕ NvCameraHalLogging:Preview profile reset
510-15235/? I/CwMcuSensor﹕ CwMcuSensor::flush: fd = 199, sensors_id = 0, path = /sys/class/htc_sensorhub/sensor_hub/flush, err = 0
223-15351/? D/NvOsDebugPrintf﹕ On-sensor flash not supported.
223-15351/? D/NvOsDebugPrintf﹕ Extended_CapabilityQuery: not supported.
223-15351/? D/NvOsDebugPrintf﹕ NvPclHwCreateModuleListOne: WARNING: Could not map module to ISP config string
223-15351/? D/NvOsDebugPrintf﹕ NvPclHwCreateModuleListOne: WARNING: Could not map module to ISP config string
223-15351/? D/NvOsDebugPrintf﹕ NvOdmImagerParameter_AFData: AF Data = 0x12501da
223-15351/? D/NvOsDebugPrintf﹕ NvCameraIspInitialize: disable3A=0x0
223-15351/? D/NvOsDebugPrintf﹕ LSC: LSC surface is not based on full res!
223-15351/? D/NvOsDebugPrintf﹕ -- NvIspAFinit -- min 226, max 552
223-15351/? D/NvOsDebugPrintf﹕ NvIspSetStats: WARNING: FM can't be enabled because AP is not enabled!!
223-15351/? E/Camera2-Parameters﹕ buildFastInfo: Unknown override AE mode: 0
223-15351/? I/Camera2Client﹕ Camera 1: Closed
223-15351/? I/Camera2ClientBase﹕ Closed Camera 1. Client was: app (PID 17929, UID 10088)
223-18026/? D/NvOsDebugPrintf﹕ NvCamScaler_OutputThread-- (error 0x0)
```

Any idea, why the camera closes and the webrtc goes for the errorCallback?
Works great as webapp, but not inside cordova container.

Answer (score 0):

Do not waste your time. Consumers are using a lot of different Android versions. I would advise you to use Crosswalk as an plugin for Cordova. Crosswalk bundles the app with an up-to-date Chrome webview that replaces the default Chrome webview of the Android device. So every Android device running the app have the exact same webview. This way old Android device can work with WebRTC, no more css fixes for older Chrome versions and no more performance problems. The downside is that Crosswalk & Cordova installed adds 58 MB of disk space. Cordova without Crosswalk adds 1,9 MB of disk space.

Using Crosswalk is very simple, just one line of code:

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview
```